# Using Mootools to replace submit buttons with links

Tags: javascript, mootools

For a particular piece of work I have to work with mootools (I'm used to jQuery). My question is what is the most efficient way to go through the page and replace all submit buttons with the class inline_submit

```
<input type="submit" class="inline_submit" name="change1" value="Change This" />
```

with links in the form

```
<a href="#change1" rel="handleinline">Change This</a>
```

where the href is = to the name of the original submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$$('input[type="submit"].inline_submit').each(function(el){
  new Element('a', { rel : 'handleinline' , href : '#'+el.get('name')})
    .set('text', el.get('value'))
    .replaces(el);
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/PJ63G/

docs:

- http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element
- http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:replaces